# OpenGL constant don't exist

Tags: c++, opengl

I haven't got GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP_HINT, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP constatns, why ? I have old version of opengl ? Where can I download new library version ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From here: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_started#OpenGL_2.0.2B_and_extensions

For Linux: http://www.opengl.org/registry/api/glext.h

For GLX: http://www.opengl.org/registry/api/glxext.h

For Windows: http://www.opengl.org/registry/api/wglext.h

Answer (score 0):

For easier access to OpenGL extensions (inc. constant values and function bindings) you can either use [glew](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) or [glee](http://www.elf-stone.com/glee.php). Interfaces in both of these libraries are similar. Glew provides access to the newest OpenGL extensions and core specifications.